# How to delete record in Parent table without affecting the Child table?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in my database, Table A and Table B.

Table A is a Master table and table B is a Transaction table. Table B have Foreign Key (IdTableA)

Example :

I already have a record in table B with IdTableA in it.

INSERT INTO Table_B VALUES (IdTableB, IdTableA, 500000);

and when I tried to delete record in Table A which is IdTableA there is an error.

I want to delete a record in Table A without affecting record in Table B

what should i do ? is it possible ?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged C#. It has nothing to do with C#. It would also help if you posted the actual error.

Comment: Well, that is the whole point of a FK.  You cannot delete a parent w/o deleting the children.  If that is a problem, there your data model is wrong, or you need to go read about RDBMS some more.

Comment: Oh sorry, im currently using c# and sql server to my application.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the error message, but most likely the `IdTableA` column is a foreign key to Table A. That means a row in Table A can't be deleted if any row in Table B references that row. There is no way to get around this except to permanently remove the foreign key.

The purpose of a foreign key is to prevent exactly this scenario. It prevents data integrity problems where rows would otherwise make no logical sense because other rows they reference do not actually exist.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: thank you sir for your explanation i understand what you mean :D